# ngIf with img depending for number returning from Observables Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngfor, angular-ng-if

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
                <div *ngIf="user?.data.hosts.foo_icon as fooIcon">
                    <img *ngIf="fooIcon === 'cloud' " class="meteo" src="./app/img/cloud.png"/>
                    <img *ngIf="fooIcon === 'sun' " class="meteo" src="./app/img/sun.png"/>
                    <img *ngIf="fooIcon === 'storm' " class="meteo" src="./app/img/storm.png"/>
                </div>
```

I am trying to display an image if my ".acknowledged" is returning "1" and if it return "0" nothing should be displayed...It works with a string but not with a number..I don't really understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `Observable`s to do that:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
  <div *ngIf="user.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon">
    <img
      *ngIf="fooIcon === 'sun' || fooIcon === 'cloud' | fooIcon === 'storm'"
      class="foo-icon"
      [src]="'./app/img/' + fooIcon + '.png'"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

If you have numbers that represent your pics, simply do a map in your TS or your service :

```
public numberToName = {
  0: 'sun',
  1: 'cloud',
  2: 'storm'
}
```

And then you can use it like that :

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
  <div *ngIf="user.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon">
    <img
      *ngIf="numberToName(fooIcon)"
      class="foo-icon"
      [src]="'./app/img/' + numberToName(fooIcon) + '.png'"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Maxime you got it but intead of 'sun' 'cloud' or 'storm' I would like to use a number..how can you do that?

Comment: If `fooIcon` is a number, my edit should be fine ;) (or you can switch the order of the map : Put the string as IDs and numbers as values)

Comment: Thanks for the help Maxime I'll try it out tomorow then tell you if its working

Comment: Your code is working as I expect but the thing is if my Json key return 0 I should  show nothing, I just must show something if it return 1... my exemple code was not that so explicit...see my update under

Comment: I create a new posts because the comment bellow was not matching my new request the link is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887546/ngif-with-depending-from-number-binding-image-in-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
    <div *ngIf="user?.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon">
        <img class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/{{fooIcon}}.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for helps but i was more looking forward to semthing like that ==>        <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
                        <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[0].foo as fooIcon">
                            <img *ngIf="acknowledgedIcon === "1" " src="./app/img/icones_sized/foo_1.png"/>
                            <img class="acknowledgedIcon" === "0" " src="./app/img/icones_sized/foo_2.png"/>
                        </div></td>

Answer (score 0):

Map you Observable and create iconId as number that you can test in html

```
userService.users
.map(user= > {
   let icon = user.data.hosts.running.foo_icon;
   let iconId = icon === 'sun' ? 1 : (icon === 'cloud' ? 2 : 3);
   return Object.assign({}, user, {iconId});
 });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help but Don't want to put to much codes line in my userService

Comment: u don't need to put this in service but in component that deal with rendering part