# ngIf with depending from number binding image in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

```
 <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
 <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[0].acknowledged as fooIcon">
 <img *ngIf="fooIcon === "1" " src="./app/img/icones_sized/tick.png"/>
 <img *ngIf="fooIcon === "0" " src="nothing_appears"/>
 </div>
```

I am trying to display an image if my ".acknowledged" is returning "1" and if it return "0" nothing should be displayed...It works with a string but not with a number..I don't really understand why..

Comment: You want it to work with both strings and numbers ? or only numbers ?

Comment: You've got double quotes nested, which won't work at all. Try `'1'`.

Comment: Just want to use numbers as '0' = notthing and '1' = show img

Comment: I try out already as '1' but it doesn't work

Comment: just use as `<img *ngIf="fooIcon === 1" src="./app/img/icones_sized/tick.png"/>`

Comment: img *ngIf="fooIcon === 1" src="./app/img/icones_sized/tick.png"/> this don't work as well..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using **`*ngIf...else`**, as

```
    <ng-template #loading>
        <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/stable_arrow_small.png"/>
    </ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[0].acknowledged===1;else loading;">
      <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/tick.png"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sure, maybe he should be, but why doesn't his original code work?

Comment: Just want to use numbers as '0' = notthing and '1' = show the image.. I update my code on to of this post

Comment: Could I set "loading" as "nothing to show" or empty, I mean if "0" is returned nothing appear in the view

Comment: Thanks a lot.. ;) it help me to found another way for info  because I wanted when it return 0 any img will display ===>  <ng-template #loading>
                                <img/>
                            </ng-template>
                            <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[0].acknowledged===0;else loading;">
                                <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/tick.png"/>
                            </div>

Comment: @the end end I do so ===>      <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
                            <ng-template #loading>
                                <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/tick.png"/>
                            </ng-template>
                            <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[0].acknowledged===1;else loading;">
                                <img/>
                            </div>
                </td>

Comment: @Aravind what do you mean by upvote? (sorry I m new in stackoverflow)